# How to insert data into database?

Tags: python, mysql

In test.txt, I have 2 lines of sentences.

```
The heart was made to be broken.
There is no surprise more magical than the surprise of being loved.
```

In codes:

```
import MySQLdb, csv, sys
db = MySQLdb.connect("host","username","password","databasename" )
c = db.cursor()
sql_drop = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Sentence"
c.execute(sql_drop)
sql = """CREATE TABLE Sentence(
     No INT,
     Sentence CHAR(255) NOT NULL)"""
csv_data=csv.reader(file("/test.txt"))
for row in csv_data:
    print row
sql_insert = "INSERT INTO Sentence (Sentence) VALUES ('%s')" % row
c.execute(sql_insert)
db.close()
```

I tried to inset into database but I got error.

```
"ProgrammingError: (1064, ""You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
 corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'There is no 
 surprise more magical than the surprise of being loved.']')' at line 1"")"
```

Any possible way for solving it?

Comment: The table you are creating isn't the same as the table you are inserting into...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO Sentence_Qaem (Sentence) VALUES (%s)", row)
```

Your `INSERT` statement doesn't escape input what is dangerous (there are SQL-injections).
You got error because one of row in file contains single quote (`'`) tat should be escaped as well.

Comment: if you pass it in as a separate query parameter then it doesn't need escaping.

Comment: And what do you have for this line: c.execute("INSERT INTO Sentence_Qaem (Sentence) VALUES (%s)", [row]) ?

Comment: In your example `row` is `tuple` which comes from `csv.reader`. Does it consist of only 1 item? Try `c.execute("INSERT INTO Sentence_Qaem (Sentence) VALUES (%s)", row[:1])`

Comment: It was original version but you commented about `TypeError`